# Show that the boundary of each of the sets is contained in $b(A)\cup b(B)$ ..

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $A$, $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the boundary of each of the sets
>   $$A\cap B,    \quad    A\setminus B,   \quad    A\cup B$$
>   is contained in $b(A)\cup b(B)$. Hint: $b(A)=A^{-}\cap (\delta(A))^{-}$.

**Case:** $A\cap B$

Since $(A∩B)^{-}\subseteq A^{-}\cap B^{-}$ , it follows that
$$\begin{align*}
b(A\cap B) &=         (A\cap B)^{-} \cap (\delta(A\cap B))^-\\\\
           &\subseteq A^{-}\cap B^{-} \cap  (\delta(A)\cup \delta(B))^{-} \\\\
           &=         A^{-} \cap B^{-} \cap  (\delta(A)^{-}\cup \delta(B)^{-})\\\\
           &=         (B^{-}\cap b(A))\cup (A^{-}\cap b(B))\\\\
           &\subseteq b(A)\cup b(B).
\end{align*}$$

How can I prove case $A\setminus B$ and $A\cup B$?

Answer (score 1):

$A\setminus B$ is $A\cap \delta(B)$, and a set has the same boundary as its complement, so you can recycle your first result.

Similarly, $A\cup B\setminus B= \delta(\delta(A)\cap\delta(B))$, so you can reduce your workload and reuse your second result, too.